# Why I can't assgin a value using loc when there are mixed data types on the dataframe? i.e. Some columns have strings other have numbers

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, indexing, element

I'm using a pandas dataframe in Python 3.6 to index files and attributes. My initial solution uses the filenames on the first column of the dataframe and numeric attributes on other columns.

When I loop through the files collecting the attributes and try to assign the values to the corresponding column on the dataframe, the values are not properly stored.

I went through several tries and finally got a code working but I don't understand why the initial solution didn't work.

Could anybody give some explanation or maybe a better solution to assign values to elements on the dataframe that doesn't set off alarms. (I know how to turn off the alarms in this case, but I would rather not do it)

The problem is exemplified on the following code. I get the same results if the dataframe is created in different ways and also if the string valued column is on different positions, e.g. second or third column on the dataframe.

Didn't try using other data types, such as bool, but I guess that the problem is related to dataframes with mixed datatypes in general.

```py
#!/usr/bin/python3

# Import standard libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# constants used as label for harmonization with the HDF5 ontology used
ROW_LENGTH = 11
COL1 = 'x1'
COL2 = 'x2'
COL3 = 'x3'

def _main():

    # Create a dataframe
    first_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[COL1, COL2, COL3])
    first_df[COL1] = ["foo"]*ROW_LENGTH
    first_df[COL2] = [np.NaN]*ROW_LENGTH
    first_df[COL3] = [np.NaN]*ROW_LENGTH

    # Go around assigning data
    for row in range(ROW_LENGTH):
        first_df[COL1][row] = "{}".format(row)
        first_df[COL2][row] = row*2 # Although it gives warning, it works
        first_df.loc[row][COL3] = row*3 # And this, that should work, don't

    print("Although no data was not stored on the third column using: first_df.loc[row][COL3]")
    print(first_df.head())
    print("\n...I can retrieve the data like: first_df[COL2][5] = '{}'".format(first_df[COL2][3]))
    print("... or like that: first_df.loc[5][COL2] = '{}'".format(first_df.loc[3][COL2]))

    # If the first row is numeric...
    second_df = pd.DataFrame(columns=[COL1, COL2, COL3])
    second_df[COL1] = [0.0]*ROW_LENGTH
    second_df[COL2] = [0.0]*ROW_LENGTH
    second_df[COL3] = [0.0]*ROW_LENGTH

    # Go around assigning data
    for row in range(ROW_LENGTH):
        second_df[COL1][row] = row*1.0
        second_df[COL2][row] = row*2.0
        second_df.loc[row][COL3] = row*3.0

    print("\nNow if I use only numeric columns, everything works as expected:")
    print(second_df.head())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _main()
```

The output is:

```
Although no data was not stored on the third column using: first_df.loc[row][COL3]
  x1   x2  x3
0  0  0.0 NaN
1  1  2.0 NaN
2  2  4.0 NaN
3  3  6.0 NaN
4  4  8.0 NaN

...I can retrieve the data like: first_df[COL2][5] = '6.0'
... or like that: first_df.loc[5][COL2] = '6.0'

Now if I use only numeric columns, everything works as expected:
    x1   x2    x3
0  0.0  0.0   0.0
1  1.0  2.0   3.0
2  2.0  4.0   6.0
3  3.0  6.0   9.0
4  4.0  8.0  12.0
```

The warning message is such

```
./test.py:24: SettingWithCopyWarning: 
A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame

See the caveats in the documentation: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy
  first_df[COL2][row] = row*2 # Although it gives warning, it works
```

This warning can be silenced using: `pd.options.mode.chained_assignment = None`

I guess that the code is self explainable about the expected results, but in short, I would like to access any element using the .loc method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `first_df.loc[row, COL3]` instead of `first_df.loc[row][COL3]`.

When you use `first_df.loc[row][COL3]`, you first create a temporary Series  with `first_df.loc[row]`, then access and modify the value at `COL3`, and drop this temporaty Series. Equivalent to:

```
tmp = first_df.loc[row]
tmp[COL3] = row*3
```

And `tmp` is never write back to the initial DataFrame.

Comment: But why does the alternative using only numeric values works fine?

Comment: As far as I understand, using `df[col][row]` behavior is intended only for viewing the data. Depending on the underlying data, `pandas` can decide to return a part of the underlying data, or a copy, and this is hardly predictable. The warning says it: writing may work, but may not. My advice is to never use `df[col][row]` and always  `df.loc[row, col]`, unless you master `pandas` enough to know when `df[col][row]` could be advantageous.